# Data transfer using ftp

Tags: ftp, data-transfer

I need to share some data from my server to colleagues. Instead of giving them host+username+password to login the server and fetch specific fold, is there any other way I just allow them to find and download the assigned files while other files is not visible to them?

Best,

Comment: FTP is both horribly insecure and horribly outdated (it really doesn't play-nice with TCP's concept of ports). Why not use DropBox or OneDrive like everyone else?

Comment: Hey Dai, dataset is several TB in size. ftp is free and relatively fast in transfer, so...

Comment: If you want something free and fast then use SSH or SFTP (SFTP is unrelated to FTP, it's more of a form of SSH that only transfers files without having real shell access). Microsoft supports OpenSSH now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse

Comment: Thanks Dai, correct me if i am wrong. With SSH, they are still able to see all my folds even they cant move things around, right?

Comment: No, that is completely untrue. Windows' OpenSSH server will respect your NTFS ACLs (SSH connections run in the security context of the remotely authenticated NT User) and you can set custom `~` home directories and enforce user-segregation.

Comment: As @Dai wrote. SFTP and FTP are just file access APIs. How the server implements the API – what file and paths it shows and what file operatinons does it allow, is completelly as server's will. It's just just a matter of using the right software. The most common OpenSSH SFTP server supports chrooting.